# Why "No overload matches this call" TypeScript Error when using custom style in react-select?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I am trying to style my react select component in my typescript react app without success. When following the docs: https://react-select.com/styles#provided-styles-and-state, I get the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<ReactSelectProps<string>>): ReactSelectClass<string>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ control: () => { width: number; }; }' has no properties in common with type 'CSSProperties'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ReactSelectProps<string>, context?: any): ReactSelectClass<string>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ control: () => { width: number; }; }' has no properties in common with type 'CSSProperties'.  TS2769
```

**Code example:**

```
const inputStyle = {
    control: () => ({

        width: 200,
      }),
```

```
<Select 
       name="Name"
       options={options}
       style={inputStyle}
 />
```

Anyone knows how to use custom styling with typescript and react select?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can import `CSSProperties` interface from '**react**' and cast the return value as `CSSProperties` of your `control` key:

```
import React, { CSSProperties } from 'react'

const inputStyle = {
  control: () => ({
    width: 200,
  } as CSSProperties),
}
```

It is because `control` is `styleFn` type which is:

```
type styleFn = (base: CSSProperties, state: any) => CSSProperties;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a typo: the `style` prop for `Select` should be `styles` (the plural).

The `style` (singular) property normally *is* supposed to be of type `CSSProperties`. But `styles` (plural) is an object with function values that return `CSSProperties`. So typescript is helping you out there, albeit somewhat cryptically.

Comment: Oh, I see thank you, that is how they do it in the example docs!
However, the Styles component I have installed doesn't have the "styles" prop.
I did npm install react-styles this morning so I expexted to get a version supporting the "styles" prop.
Do you know how to get/upgrade to a version that supports it? @Garrett Motzner

Comment: Odd, because it's in the source code atm (version 3.1.0): https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/packages/react-select/src/Select.js#L285. Make sure you installed the right package and are importing the right component, I guess.... As far as `react-` _`styles`_ goes, (as opposed to `react-select`), I'm not sure how that interacts. Maybe remove that until you get it working?

Comment: @Sequinex If you want to install typings for `react-select` ([@types/react-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-select)), do this: `npm i @types/react-select`.

Comment: Do you _need_ the types though, @AjeetShah? If you don't have them, it should still work. It's not a type issue, fundementally (I think).

Comment: It works without installing typings. But having typings installed helps catch errors beforehand. It just makes development easier, nothing else. I want to make sure that OP knows how to install typings, to install it or not it is their choice.